# Python insert list items into every 3rd slot of larger list

Tags: python, list, merge

So I have two lists in python,

```
letters = ['1', '2', '4', '5', '7', '8']
list = ['3', '6', '9']
```

and I would like to merge these two lists into one.
That looks like so:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Here is the code I am running

```
letters = ['1','2','4','5','7','8']
list = ['3','6','9']

new_list = []
n = 2

length = len(list)
i = 0

while i < length:
    for start_index in range(0, len(letters), n):
        new_list.extend(letters[start_index:start_index+n])
        print(list[i])
        new_list.append(list[i])
        i += 1

new_list.pop()
print(new_list)
```

which results in:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

whilst I am expecting

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

also the order is not alpha-numeric, the goal is to iterate through the smaller list and place each item into every 3rd slot of the larger list.

Comment: What should happen with potential duplicate values? E.g. `[1, 2, 4]` and `[1, 3, 5]`: should the result just be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` or should some `error` be given? Or should the result be `[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`? Solutions will differ depending on what you want to do. Is sorting required or does the order not matter? Can one list itself contain duplicates e.g. `[1, 1, 2]` and how to handle that?

Comment: well one list will always be twice the size of the other so using the two lists. a[7,9,8,2,4,6] and b[f,g,p] the results should be [7,9,f,8,2,g,4,6,p]

Comment: why do you have this line `new_list.pop()`? Without this line, your code works

Comment: I had an answer, but as @enke observes, your code works apart from the unwanted `pop()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the numbers given are just placeholders, and not meant to actually be sorted:

One way to interleave items would be using iterators manually:

```
letters = ['1','2','4','5','7','8']
lst = ['3','6','9']

a = iter(letters)
b = iter(lst)
new_list = []
try:
    while True:
        if len(new_list) % 3 == 2:
            new_list.append(next(b))
        else:
            new_list.append(next(a))
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Or for an entirely different, more terse, solution, you could use `itertools.chain` alongside `zip()`:

```
import itertools

letters = ['1','2','4','5','7','8']
lst = ['3','6','9']

new_list = list(itertools.chain(*zip(letters[::2], letters[1::2], lst)))
# letters[::2]   ->  1, 4, 7
# letters[1::2]  ->  2, 5, 8
# lst            ->  3, 6, 9
#
# zip(...) -> (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)
# chain(...) -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your own code and used `for` loop instead of `while`:

```py
letters = ['1','2','4','5','7','8']
myList = ['3','6','9']

new_list = []
length = len(myList) + len(letters)
j = 0
for i in range(1,length+1):
  if i % 3 == 0:
    new_list.append(myList[i//3 - 1])
    j -= 1
  else:
    new_list.append(letters[i + j - 1])
print(new_list)
```

##### Output

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Let's have another example:

```py
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
myList = ['1','2','3']

new_list = []
length = len(myList) + len(letters)
j = 0
for i in range(1,length+1):
  if i % 3 == 0:
    new_list.append(myList[i//3 - 1])
    j -= 1
  else:
    new_list.append(letters[i + j - 1])
print(new_list)
```

##### Output

```
['a', 'b', '1', 'c', 'd', '2', 'e', 'f', '3']
```

Note that this only works when the number of elements in the `myList` variable will be multiple of 3.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.10, you can use `itertools.pairwise`:

```
import itertools

letters = ['1','2','4','5','7','8']
new = ['3', '6', '9']

result = []
for pair, single in zip(itertools.pairwise(letters), new):
    result.extend(pair)
    result.append(single)
```

Or more generally (and for a pairwise replacement for before 3.10):

```
def by_n(iterable, n):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)

result = []
for triple, single in zip(by_n(letters, 3), new):
    result.extend(triple)
    result.append(single)
```